# objective C Unable to release UIViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-leaks, crash

i'm having a subclass of UIViewController also implementing the UITableViewDelegate.
Basically, there is a UITableView displayed, and selection of a cell pushes a new view.
Here is about how the code looks:

```
// NavigationContentsViewController.h
@interface NavigationContentsViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {

    IBOutlet UITableView * newsTable;
    UIActivityIndicatorView * activityIndicator;
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// placed in NavigationContentsViewController.m

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSInteger selectedCellItem = indexPath.row;

    TableViewController *fvController = [[TableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TableViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    fvController.selectedCellItem = selectedCellItem;
    fvController.link = [links objectAtIndex:selectedCellItem];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:fvController animated:YES];
    [fvController release];  // #1 if removed everything works fine but getting a leak
    fvController = nil;      // #2
}
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//  TableViewController.h
@interface TableViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>{
    NSInteger selectedCellItem;
    IBOutlet UIWebView *myWebView;
    NSString *link;
    UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator;
}
```

So, when  user selects a cell, a new UIWebView is pushed.
There is also an Activity Indicator displayed until the webView has finished loading.

My problem is that if the user chooses to go back from the webView to the previous view (the one with the table) before the webView has finished loading, the app crashes, getting this error: "[TableViewController respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x4b57460"

If the webView has finished loading and user selects to go back everything is fine.

I managed to fix this problem by removing the two lines marked with #1 and #2 in the code, but then i get a memory leak (as i do not release the TableViewController).

Still trying to understand what is happening. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect you are setting your TableViewController as the delegate for the UIWebView, and you missed this message in [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIWebView/delegate):

> **Important:** Before releasing an instance of `UIWebView` for which you have set a delegate, you must first set its delegate property to `nil`. This can be done, for example, in your dealloc method.

If you forget to remove the delegate in dealloc, the web view may eventually try to send a delegate message even though the delegate no longer exists. Boom.

Comment: This is exactly what i was doing, this is exactly what i was missing... Thanks a lot for replying! Accepted answer ;)